# How to get rid of ACT error while using async user event in RTL?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I decided to create a simple tic-tac-toe game to practice testing, but after first test i had written I got this annoying act warning. My code isn't async so I don't know how to solve it.

here is the component code:

```
    const Board = () => {

    const [currentSign,setCurrentSign] = useState<"cross" | "circle">("cross")
    const [board, setBoard] = useState (new Array(9).fill(null))

  const handleUserClick = (e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        // @ts-ignore
      if (board[e.target.dataset.number] !==null) return
      // @ts-ignore

        // @ts-ignore
        setBoard(p=>p.map((el,i)=>i===+e.target.dataset.number?currentSign:el))
        setCurrentSign(p=>p==="cross"?"circle":"cross")
  }


    return (
        <div onClick={handleUserClick} data-testid="board" className="board">
            {new Array(9).fill(null).map((_,i)=>(
                <div key={i} data-number={i} data-testid="board-child" className={
                    `board-child 
                     ${board[i] === null ? "" : board[i] === "cross" ? "cross" : "circle"}`}/>
                ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Here is the test:

```
test("when user clicks second time, the clicked element gets 'circle' class", async () => {
            render(<Board />);

        const boardChildren = screen.getAllByTestId("board-child");
            await user.click(boardChildren[0]);
            await user.click(boardChildren[1]);
            expect(boardChildren[1]).toHaveClass("circle");
    });
```

The test passes, but leaves with with the act warning

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out it was RTL inner error and the solution was to just update RTL to the latest (v14) version.